# android replacing nulls with TBD in listview

Tags: android

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.mytaskslayout, cursor, new String[] {"Aircraft","Discrepancy", "ARR_FLT", "ARR_Gate", "DPT_FLT", "DPT_Gate"}, new int[] {R.id.ac, R.id.discrepancy, R.id.arrac, R.id.arrgate, R.id.dptac, R.id.dptgate});
```

Here some of the values are null. I don't want to display null but TBD. Can I do something here. (I CAN NOT CHANGE SQL)

Comment: There is no SQL in your question...

Answer (score 0):

iterate through your array (populating the listview) and any value in the array that equals null make it equal TBD

but from what im seeing your creating your arrays on the fly and not from a database

```
new String[] {"Aircraft","Discrepancy", "ARR_FLT", "ARR_Gate", "DPT_FLT", "DPT_Gate"}, new int[] {R.id.ac, R.id.discrepancy, R.id.arrac, R.id.arrgate, R.id.dptac, R.id.dptgate}
```

Comment: ya, I am getting data in a cursor.

Comment: well ok but usually cursor would look like this:  Cursor c = myDB.query("querytxt").  at least in my experience.  but regardless.  i think there is something being lost in communication here.  because your using a string and an int array to populate your cursor.  i see no links to a database.  i also do not see any NULLs in your arrays.  basically though with what you have supplied i would say to pull your arrays out of the cursor and iterate through them for nulls.  but once again, i dont see any of these being null.  its a string array, and the int array is for references to resources.

Comment: cursor = assignment.getAcceptedTasks(id); This is how I am getting data from SQLite. And binding it to listView using SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: regardless you should be able to iterate through that cursor and change the values prior to displaying them in the listview.

Comment: I am iterating thro' cursor and checking for null. "cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DPT_FLT")).equals("null")" How do I "set" another value there ?

Comment: is there no cursor.setvalue like function?  i know theres a way, just dont have eclipse in front of me.  ill try to find it a little later